# Trigger HTML POST/Form submit w/o JavaScript

Tags: forms, submit, noscript

I have a timed page that I need to use to submit a form upon the end of a specified time period.

The usage would be: User visits page, 90 seconds later all form data is submitted and user is redirected to next page.

The user is well aware that the page they are on is timed (its for a web-only experiment), so I'm not worried about "unfriendly" browser behavior on this page.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid using JavaScript (some of our targeted users are using no-script for various reasons, but if its the only way, so be it), and would also like to avoid just passing variables through the URL (to cut down on the possibility of spoofing). It is easy enough to set a META refresh tag to do the redirecting, but at the end of the time period I need some way for the response header to be set as if the submit button was clicked, whether or not it actually was.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts you might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done.